# Confusing application of power residue reciprocity in Milne's CFT

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Hey I am trying to figure out the details of the proof of Theorem 5.14 (p.246) in Milne's CFT [(see here)](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf). I hope somebody is familiar with this. But let me sketch the proof and what I don't understand. Please feel free to answer any of the questions below.

> **Theorem 5.14** Let $x, y, z$ be relative prime positive integers such that $p$ does not divide $xyz$ and $x^p + y^p = z^p$. Then for every prime $q$ dividing $xyz$, the equation $q^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod{p^2}$ holds.

**Proof**

Let $\zeta\in \mathbb C$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity. Now we consider $K = \mathbb Q[\zeta]$ and its ring of integers $\mathcal O_K = \mathbb Z[\zeta]$. Note that $(p) = \mathfrak p^{p-1}$ where $\mathfrak p$ is the prime ideal generated by $\pi = 1-\zeta$.

We know $z^p = \prod\limits_{i=0}^{p-1} (x+\zeta^i y)$. Because $x+\zeta^iy$ are pairwise relatively prime, their principal ideals are $p$-th powers of ideals in $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$.

This implies that the $p$-th power residue symbol $\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right) = 1$ for all $\beta \in \mathbb Z[\zeta]$ relatively prime to $\alpha = \frac{x+\zeta y}{x+y} = 1 - \frac{y\pi}{x+y}$ with the prime element $\pi=1-\zeta$. (Q1)

Setting $\beta = q^{p-1}$ one can also check $\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right) = 1$. (Q2)

The power residue reciprocity theorem says $\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right) ^{-1} = (\alpha,\beta)_{\mathfrak p}$ where $(\alpha,\beta)_{\mathfrak p}$ is the Hilbert symbol in $K$ ($=\mathbb Q[\zeta]$).

One can compute $(\alpha,\beta)_{\mathfrak p} = \zeta^{\mathrm{Tr}_{K/\mathbb Q}(\eta)}$ where $\eta = \frac{\beta-1}{p}\frac{\alpha-1}{\pi}$. (Q3)

From the triviality of the power residue symbols above we get $(\alpha,\beta)_{\mathfrak p} = 1$ or equivalently $p$ divides the integer $\mathrm{Tr}_{K/\mathbb Q}(\eta)$.

We calculate $\mathrm{Tr}(\frac{\alpha-1}{\pi}) = \mathrm{Tr}(-\frac{y}{x+y}) = -\frac{y}{x+y}\cdot (p-1)$, which is relatively prime to $p$. Hence $\frac{\beta-1}{p} = \frac{q^{p-1}-1}{p}$ is divisible by $p$.

**Questions**

(Q1) I understand that $\alpha$ generates a principal (fractional) ideal that is a $p$-th power of another (fractional) ideal. Why does this imply $\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right) = 1$ for all $\beta \in \mathbb Z[\zeta]$ relatively prime to $\alpha$?

(Q2) Clearly $\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right) = \left(\frac q\alpha\right)^{p-1} = \left(\frac q\alpha\right)^{-1} = 1 \iff \left(\frac q\alpha\right) = 1$, but how do you continue from there?

(Q3) Just before in Milne's CFT on pages 244f (in particular Proposition 5.12), there is a description how to compute exactly these Hilbert symbols. But I cannot relate that description to $(\alpha,\beta)_{\pi}=(\alpha,\beta)_{\mathfrak p} = \zeta^{\mathrm{Tr}_{K/\mathbb Q}(\eta)}$.

**Last remark**

Literature that I am familiar with is Milne's course notes [(see here)](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/index.html), Serre's "Local fields", and Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory" (which includes his book on class field theory). Any advice on the questions will be welcomed but I can parse similar language as in those books fastest.

Comment: I have a vague impression that Wiles' paper on explicit reciprocity laws contains a similar formula to your question $3.$ But I am not very sure.

Comment: In the article by G. Gras & R. Quême, "Vandiver's papers on cyclotomy revisited and FLT", Publ. Math. Besançon, 2012, 2, 47-111, you will find complete calculations on the so called Fermat quotients $q^{p-1} - 1 / p, using power residue symbols, not only in the first case (p not dividing xyz) but also in the second, and in a simpler way than Milne's, if I remember well. Actually the authors study the so called Strong FLT, which is an equation in Z[zeta].

Answer (score 1):

Q1: There is a typo in the manuscript: instead of $(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}) = 1$ it should read $(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}) = 1$, and this holds for trivial reasons: $(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}) = (\frac{\beta}{{\mathfrak a}^p}) = (\frac{\beta}{{\mathfrak a}})^p = 1$.

Q2: This problem dissolves since now you need to prove $(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}) = 1$, which follows directly from $(\frac{\alpha}{q}) = 1$.